# Unable to pass Json file to a Function from Google Cloud Services in Android App

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform

I want to use Google Cloud Services APIs in my Android App and I am trying to Use `OAuth`
for server authentication using the function below (which i got from this link: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually):

I am trying to pass the `JSON filepath` to a function in an Android App but `Logcat` says File not Found.

```
try {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Gone Inside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    authExplicit("/app/JsonFile.json"); 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} catch (IOException e) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

But I'm getting the following error in the Android App:

```
019-10-08 16:01:06.888 18008-18008/com.example.home W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:43371): avc: denied { search } for name="ctx" dev="debugfs" ino=15090 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c212,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2019-10-08 16:01:07.028 18008-18151/com.example.home E/LB: fail to open file: No such file or directory
```

I don't understand why I can't access my `JSON` file from the App folder.
Please help me with this.